# Why is TextMate calling "mate --c" when compiling and giving errors

Tags: textmate

When I compile any LaTeX document using TextMate (2.0b6.8) I get the following error/warning message after the standard LaTeX or pdfTeX output:

```
mate: invalid option -- c mate r1577 (2012-06-26)

Usage: mate [-awlrdnhv] [file ...]

Options:

    -a, --async
    Do not wait for file to be closed by TextMate.

    -w, --wait
    Wait for file to be closed by TextMate.

    -l, --line
    Place caret on line after loading file.

    -r, --recent
    Add file to Open Recent menu.

    -d, --change-dir
    Change TextMates working directory to that of the file.

    -n, --no-reactivation
    After edit with -w, do not re-activate the calling app.

    -h, --help
    Show this information.

    -v, --version
    Print version information. If multiple files are given, a project
    is created consisting of these files, -a is then default and -w
    will be ignored (e.g. "mate *.tex"). By default mate will not wait
    for the file to be closed except when used as filter:

        ls *.tex|mate|sh -w implied mate -|cat -n -w

    implied (read from stdin) An exception is made if the command is
    started as something which ends with "_wait". So to have a command
    with --wait as default, you can create a symbolic link like this:
    ln -s mate mate_wait
```

The LaTeX files compile fine, so it's not a major issue, but it clogs up the Textmate log window and I have to scroll up to find any actual warnings/errors.
Why is the `mate` command even being called, let alone with an invalid option, when I compile and run a TeX document?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I can confirm, that this happens, though i couldn't find anything in the config or bundle settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

René suggested that I had an out of date version of mate installed. This turns out not to be the case, but led me to the correct solution.

I still had a copy of TextMate 1.5.11 on my computer, which includes an older version of mate bundled with it. Even though /usr/local/bin/mate was up to date, TextMate 2.0b6.8 was, for some reason, running the old version of mate bundled with TextMate 1.5.11 instead of the correctly installed newer version.

I fixed the problem by replacing the version of mate inside the 1.5.11 bundle – now there is no error.

However, it seems to me that TextMate should be calling the version stored within its own bundle, rather than that bundled in the old version.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you still have an outdated version of `mate` installed. You should be able to solve your problem by reinstalling “Shell Support” inside Preferences→Terminal.

> Why is the mate command even being called, let alone with an invalid option, when I compile and run a TeX document?

`mate` is used to update the “gutter marks” for the current file [[1](https://github.com/textmate/latex.tmbundle/commit/8c08665966414014000a840b457e1b861d303b23)]. These gutter marks indicate (LaTeX) errors and warnings on the left side of the editor window. Support for gutter marks was added in TextMate v2.0-beta.3 [[2](https://github.com/textmate/textmate/blob/master/Applications/TextMate/about/Changes.md)].